# How would you analyze a change in heap memory allocation?

Tags: java, profiling, heap-dump, thread-dump

I'm trying to figure out the best way to analyse why an application suddenly allocates memory more often than before. For a better understanding what I mean, take a look at this memory graph.

[image]

As you can see it runs fine for a few days and then allocates memory way faster.

What tool can help me here? What is the best approach?

I have already taken several thread dumps but there is nothing noticeable. I dumped the heap twice and compared the objects but that didn't help either.

I don't think it is a memory problem because the full gc can always clean up the same amount of memory. It rather looks like some routine started to run which requires a lot of memory. It is not related to heavier usage as it turns back to normal as soon as I restart the application.

Comment: *It rather looks like some routine started* - it's your application, isn't it? do you have configured such a routine may be?

Comment: Yes it is mine but there is nothing that is scheduled at that time. Also this behavior always occurs only after some days.

Comment: may be your application requires memory faster, may be that is just normal for you?

Comment: do you consider if this memory allocation growth can be related to heavier usage of an application? do you have similar graphs of number of connections / hits per second / something else?

Comment: It is not related to heavier usages. As soon as I restart the application it looks normal again. I'll add this to questions.